# List process for current user

Tags: powershell

As an administrator I can get a users processes by running this

`Get-Process -IncludeUserName | Where UserName -match test`

But as a non-administrator I can't use `-IncludeUserName` becuase "The 'IncludeUserName' parameter requires elevated user rights".

So if I'm logged on as the user test, how do I list only his processes and not everything that's running?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that through WMI. Here is an excerpt of an article you can find [here](https://p0w3rsh3ll.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/find-the-owner-of-a-process/).

```
$View = @(
 @{l='Handles';e={$_.HandleCount}},
 @{l='NPM(K)';e={ (Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId).NonpagedSystemMemorySize/1KB -as [int]}},
 @{l='PM(K)';e={ $_.PrivatePageCount/1KB -as [int]}},
 @{l='WS(K)';e={ $_.WorkingSetSize/1KB -as [int]}},
 @{l='VM(M)';e={ $_.VirtualSize/1mB -as [int]}},
 @{l='CPU(s)';e={ (Get-Process -Id $_.ProcessId).CPU -as [int]}},
 @{l='Id';e={ $_.ProcessId}},
 'UserName'
 @{l='ProcessName';e={ $_.ProcessName}}
)
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | % { $_ | 
    Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name UserName -Value {
        '{0}\{1}' -f $this.GetOwner().Domain,$this.GetOwner().User
    } -Force -PassThru
} | ? UserName -match $env:USERNAME | ft $View -AutoSize
```

Comment: There is a little mistake in the script: It shows processes of user 'administrator' as well as the processes of user 'admin'  under whom I logged in. There should be something different rather than `-match`

Comment: replace -match with -eq

Comment: Of cause I tried it. It does not work, since the domain name is also included in UserName

Answer (score 14):

This is faster, one line, doesn't require admin.

> `Get-Process | ? {$_.SI -eq (Get-Process -PID $PID).SessionId}`

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more ?  I used it and it worked well

Comment: Sure. `Get-Process` returns all of the processes. That is piped to `?` (alias for `Where-Object`). So it loops over all of the processes looking for `$_.SI` (SessionId) equal to the session ID of the `$PID`, which is an automatic variable (process id of the current task). Basically saying, "List all processes where the session ID is equal to the session ID of the currently running process". Since we're looking for the current user, the `$PID` should share the same session id we're looking for. You could have multiple sessions, but then you'd modify. Current user implies whatever is logged in.

Comment: That's a nice one, although you'll get a few system processes that interact with your session.

Answer (score 9):

`Get-Process` alone will not give you this information, you'll need WMI:

```
$owners = @{}
gwmi win32_process |% {$owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user}
$ps = get-process | select processname,Id,@{l="Owner";e={$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}}
foreach($p in $ps) {
    if($p.Owner -eq $env:USERNAME) {
        $p
    }
}
```

Comment: Work really well. Can only mark one post as the answer though and David Brabant was first.

Comment: Yes, he deserves it and I upvoted his answer as well.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your code. Based on this, I created a modified version to allow users to kill (a subset of) their own processes:

```
#Script to allow users to kill (a subset of) their own processes 
#Based on : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35195221/list-process-for-current-user
#Previously we used Task Nanny created by Michel Stevelmans which is a lot faster, but it did not show a process that was causing issues for our users.
$UserProcesses = @()
$Owners = @{}
Get-WmiObject win32_process | Foreach{$owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user}
$Processes = Get-Process | select processname,Description,Id,@{l="Owner";e={$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}}
Foreach($Process in $Processes)
{
    IF($process.Owner -eq $env:USERNAME)
    {
        $UserProcesses += $Process
    }
}
$UserProcessesToExclude = @(
    'concentr', #Citrix Connection Center
    'conhost', #Console Window Host
    'dwm', #Desktop Windows Manager
    'explorer', #Explorer
    'Receiver', #Citrix Receiver Application
    'rundll32', #Windows host process (Rundll32)
    'ssonsvr', #Citrix  Receiver 
    'taskhost' #Host Process for Windows Tasks
    'wfcrun32' #Citrix Connection Manager
    'wfshell' #Citrix wfshell shell
)

$UserProcesses | Where{$_.ProcessName -notin $UserProcessesToExclude} | Out-GridView -Title 'Task killer - Select the process(es) you want to kill. Hold CTRL to select multiple processes.' -PassThru | Foreach{Stop-Process -id $_.Id}
```